# Topos with sets as subobject classifier

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

In the computer science literature I have seen cases in which they move from booleans to $\mathsf{Set}$ for obtaining a "proof-relevant" version of a concept (especially in formalisations).

As the booleans work like the subobject classifier of $\mathsf{Set}$, and in some sense it accounts for the truth values, I wonder if there is something like a topos in which $\mathsf{Set}$ itself (somehow, I don't know) is the subobject classifier, and if this gives a version of proof-relevant set theory?

I know it is a bit sketchy, but trying to formalise this I get lost by size problems.

Comment: I think what you want is not a topos where $Set$ is the subibject classifier, but rather a $2$-topos with $Set$ as its underlying $1$-topos : going from $2$ to $Set$ looks more like categorification if I'm not mistaken; in that $0$-topoi are akin to Heyting algebras/locales (I read something along these lines in Baez/Shulman's "$n$-categories and Cohomology")

Comment: Another way to think of this is that the thing you describe is moving from the subobject fibration on $\mathbf{Set}$ to the family fibration over $\mathbf{Set}$; and one of the ways the latter differs from the former is that there is no generic object (the fibrational cousin of a subobject classifier), essentially because of the drastic change in size of the fibers.

Comment: What you want to say is that $Set$ classifies (discrete op)fibrations in $CAT$, a sufficiently big category of categories of which $Set$ is an object.  See Weber's https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-007-9079-2